Force change a user's screen width for mobile browsers?
I'm looking to implement a feature to force a users screen width since some of our features aren't mobile compatible yet.
So if a user wants to perform a certain action, I would have a button like "Switch to desktop view", but I'm having trouble finding a solution to make this work. Currently using Javascript + Angular v16. Does anyone have experience with something similar or know if this is possible?
We started development with desktop views first (I know, not ideal), so I'm running into this issue in a couple areas while setting up a lot of media queries.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

If you simply use:  ?
